# Determine the linear transformation given matrix relative to bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $B=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and $B'=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(-1,-1,1)\}$ be (ordered) bases of $V=\mathbb{R^3}$. Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $$\left[T\right]_{B',B}=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\\\end{matrix}\right].$$ Find $T(x,y,z)$ and hence obtain $[T]_{B,B'}$.

**My attempt:**

I formed the augmented matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1&0&-1&a&d&g\\0&1&-1&b&e&h\\0&0&1&c&f&i\\\end{array}\right]$$
where $(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i)$ are the elements of $B$ after applying $T$ to it. Now, I converted the left part of this augmented matrix to it's RREF form and equated the right part to the given matrix $[T]_{B',B}$ and solved for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$. But I don't have any clue on how to proceed further.